# Meanin of "catch up to" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> ‘Isn’t it his duty to write fancy stuff?’ asked the prince, still
>   trying to **catch up to** the plans.

The prince is discussing plans to catch a thief with his brothers. However, he is struggling to suggest a good idea because he is not as intelligent as his brothers. He is asking a question regarding a poet who is one of the suspects.

How would you rephrase the phrase "catch up to"?

Comment: Did you try checking a dictionary? What did you find? You can [edit] your question to add more info.

Comment: I consulted some dictionaries, but could not find a perfect or satisfactory meaning for the given context.

Comment: It's always best to include which dictionaries you checked, and what you saw when you looked there. A beginner might parse this as three separate words [catch][up][to], a verb with a double preposition [catch][up to] or a phrasal verb followed by a preposition [catch up][to]. We have no idea how you approached this, because you've said nothing other than "I consulted some dictionaries." Therefore, it's harder for us to give you a helpful information that will help you solve similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+up

In one of the meanings:

> 3. To bring some activity to completion or to a state of currentness: *On the weekends, I catch up on reading the daily newspapers because I don't have time during the week.*

Now that you ask

> How would you rephrase the phrase "catch up to"?

[Update according to JeremyC's comment]

> ‘Isn’t it his duty to write fancy stuff?’ asked the prince, still trying to **keep up with** the plans.